# Adicionar atributo em um json

Tags: react-native, async-await

Como eu faço pra adicionar um atributo a mais em todos os elementos de um `JSON` que eu recebo, pra depois exibir na tela?

Quando eu tento fazer um `map` no `JSON` que eu recebo da requisição e adicionar o item no estado não da certo por causa do `await async`, ai ele só adiciona 1.

Preciso adicionar, em um `array` de objetos que eu recebo no `JSON` um atributo qtd em cada objeto, quando utilizo o `Spread operator ([...dados,{qtd:0}])` ele não faz em todo o `array`.

Exemplo:

```
const montaAlgoMais = async () => {

    try {
  
        const res = await axios.get(url)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                    data.map((item) => {
                        return setAlgoMais([...algoMais,{...item,qtd:0}])
                    })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você passar um objeto com mais atributos é só copiar os dados com a técnica [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) como no exemplo:

```js
const data = {
  'id': 1, 
  'name': 'example 1'
}

const finalData = { ... data, source: new Date() };

console.log(finalData);
```

esse comando também funciona para `array` de objetos exemplo:

```js
const datas = [
  {
    'id': 1, 
    'name': 'example 1'
  }, 
  {
    'id': 2, 
    'name': 'example 2'
  }
]

const finalData = datas.map(data => {
  return {... data, source: new Date()};
});

console.log(finalData);
```

Na sua solução está tudo errado, você misturou as coisa e o correto é:

```
const montaAlgoMais = async () => {
    try {  
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        const newData = res.data.map(item => { 
            return { ...item, qtd: 0};
        });
        setAlgoMais(newData);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: como eu faço isso, recebendo as informações de uma requisição em axios? por que eu faço a adição com operador spread, e parece que ele faz só uma vez

Comment: alguém pode me ajudar???

Comment: @MatheusSaleh como vem esse `json`? eu te dei todas as cartas qual a dificuldade

Comment: `return (setData([...data]))` primeiro problema isso não é necessário!

Comment: Se você recebe um `array` e precisa criar mais uma chave dentro de cada posição precisa utilizar `map` como eu te monstrei no segundo exemplo. @MatheusSaleh

Comment: Pode ser que eu me expressei mau, mas eu informei no problema. Eu recebo as informações de um json.  Eu faço uma requisição com await no axios e recebo um json.E se eu coloco ele com operador spread , ele funciona, mas só se for no json todo. Quero adicionar um campo a todos os objetos, só que quando eu uso um foreach ou map, nos dados que eu recebo, ele só retorna 1 objeto dos 20 que vem no json.

Comment: então você fez errado alguma coisa, passa na pergunta o que você realmente fez ai fica mais tranquilo opinar! de um modo geral se está errando alguma coisa, então na pergunta coloque o que está fazendo e o que espera que aconteça !!! fico no aguardo.

Comment: adicionei a pergunta o que eu fiz

Comment: Do jeito que ele esta la, ele me retorna um array com 1 objeto , e se eu atualizo a pagina , vai aumentando, mas sempre traz o mesmo objeto

Comment: Fiz a edição e tudo o que você tinha feito está errado, observer o correto @MatheusSaleh

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Desculpe pela falta de coerência das perguntas , eu não tenho muita experiencia com React Native.